# How to iterate rows in R and apply if conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have a tidy dataset which some of the columns looks like below:

```
  my_col_a      my_col_b     my_col_c 
    (chr)        (chr)       (chr) 
1   happy         sad          -     
2    sad           -        defiant    
3   happy          -           -     
4     -            -           -     
5   excited        -           -
```

How can I count how many words distinct of '-' there is per row in R? The desired output would be:

```
 my_col_a      my_col_b     my_col_c  nmr_moods
    (chr)        (chr)       (chr)    (double)
1   happy         sad          -         2
2    sad           -        defiant      2
3   happy          -           -         1
4     -            -           -         0
5   excited        -           -         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  my_col_a = c("happy", "sad", "happy", "-", "excited"),
  my_col_b = c("sad", rep("-", 4)),
  my_col_c = c("-", "defiant", rep("-", 3)))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(my_col_d = sum(c_across(my_col_a:my_col_c) != "-")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c my_col_d
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <int>
1 happy    sad      -               2
2 sad      -        defiant         2
3 happy    -        -               1
4 -        -        -               0
5 excited  -        -               1
```

Answer (score 3):

**base**

```r
df <- structure(list(my_col_a = c("happy", "sad", "happy", "-", "excited"
), my_col_b = c("sad", "-", "-", "-", "-"), my_col_c = c("-", 
                                                         "defiant", "-", "-", "-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                         -5L))



df$nmr_moods <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(!grepl("^-$", x)))
df
#>   my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c nmr_moods
#> 1    happy      sad        -         2
#> 2      sad        -  defiant         2
#> 3    happy        -        -         1
#> 4        -        -        -         0
#> 5  excited        -        -         1
```

**or**

```
df$nmr_moods <- rowSums(df != "-")

  my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c nmr_moods
1    happy      sad        -         2
2      sad        -  defiant         2
3    happy        -        -         1
4        -        -        -         0
5  excited        -        -         1
```

**tidyverse**

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(nmr_moods = rowSums(across(everything(), ~!grepl("^-$", .x))))
#>   my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c nmr_moods
#> 1    happy      sad        -         2
#> 2      sad        -  defiant         2
#> 3    happy        -        -         1
#> 4        -        -        -         0
#> 5  excited        -        -         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is also another tidyverse solution for your purpose:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(my_count = pmap_dbl(., 
                             ~ sum(str_detect(c(...), "-", negate = TRUE))))


  my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c my_count
1    happy      sad        -        2
2      sad        -  defiant        2
3    happy        -        -        1
4        -        -        -        0
5  excited        -        -        1
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner solution with `apply`and `str_count`:

```
library(stringr)
df$count <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(str_count(x, "^[A-Za-z]+$")))
```

Result:

```
df
  my_col_a my_col_b my_col_c count
1    happy      sad        -     2
2      sad        -  defiant     2
3    happy        -        -     1
4        -        -        -     0
5  excited        -        -     1
```

Data: @Claudio's